# Why do I have the same summernote div appear for all the lis in my list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, summernote

I have multiple lis in an unordered list which when clicked gives me a summernote div. The problem is that all these lis have the same summernote div meaning when I click on a li and change the text in the summernote div the text changes for all the divs.

My list:

```
<ul id = "courseNav">              
         <li class = "topics" style = "margin-top: -12px"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
         <li class = "topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
         <li class = "topics"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
</ul>
```

My summernote code:

```
<div id = "editor">Type something...</div>

$('#editor').summernote();
```

Every li I click in my list will have the same summernote div will appear. How can I fix this?

My button code;
`$("#add").click(function() {
   $("#courseNav").append("<li><a href = "#">added</a></li>");
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your code. But according to what your saying I would suggest using different ids for each  summernote . So every list will have its own summernote with unique id in that way changing the text in one summernote will not change the rest

Hey check this blog out :

http://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/

It shows how to add a li on a list dinamically

Comment: Yeah but I have a button which adds an li to my list.

Comment: Could you post a complete code on [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Sorry I am away from my computer right now. Can you help me with the code I have provided here?

Comment: Well first of all are you clicking in button or li-s. And what are you truing to do, this is so confusing.

Comment: I am clicking the button to add a new li. When the li is clicked.the summer note div appears. The problem is that the when I type some text on the summer note div on an li and I click on a different li the same text appears. How can I fix this?